# Basic Event Binding in Angular not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, typescript

I am incredibly new to angular and was trying to learn how to use event binding. I began implementing a few, but realized even when I was using basic ones the output would not be as expected. Actually, I wouldn't get any output at all. One example is the following, where I did not receive any output.

ts file

```
export class Personal {
   test() { 
    alert("Hello");
   //console.log("Hello") 
   }
}
```

HTML file

```
    <button  (click)="test()" >Click here!</button>
```

With this, in my component's ts and HTML files, respectively, I should receive a popup alert when clicked, but I received nothing.

I also used console.log("hello") and nothing showed up in the console when I inspected. The web app servers without any issues, and the other buttons and text display correctly, even with the different bindings. It's just the event binding that I am having trouble with. I am on mac if that may be an issue.

With interpolation and property binding, it worked fine. However, I have the same issue when I try two-way binding, so I think it is an issue on a specific end.

For two way binding I used

ts file

`userInput: string = '';`

HTML file

```
<input name="userInput" [(ngModel)]="userInput">
<p>{{userInput}}</p>
```

The input shows up, and I am able to input text. However, it does not function as it should. (I had to add an import statement for forms module and add it to the imports in my component declaration)

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-pesonal',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  templateUrl: './personal.component.html',
  styleUrl: './personal.component.css'
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you forgetting the component annotation? Is your component standalone or part of a module?

Comment: @BrandonTaylor

Hey, my component is the initial component created after the project is created. It is a standalone component and does not rely on any other components and is not part of a module. I also believe I do have the component annotation. @Component({ selector: 'app-personal', standalone: true, imports: [CommonModule], templateUrl: './personal.component.html', styleUrl: './personal.component.css' })

Comment: Hard to say what's wrong with the `test()` method, I don't see anything wrong with it. Any chance you can reproduce the issue in a StackBlitz?

Comment: @BrandonTaylor Hey, I've uploded the code for the files here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-yfbgsa?file=src%2Findex.html

The code for the main template can be found in main.ts and the html code can be found in its templateURL which is personal.component.html which is found in the personal folder

Comment: Just adding on, for some reason the two way binding works properly only on stackblitz even though I used the same code

Comment: Also adding that the event binding works properly on stack blitz but not on my browser, the IDE I use is VS Code. Unsure why this is the case

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you. Without being able to replicate the issue, it's difficult to diagnose what might be wrong. Are there any console errors?

Comment: @BrandonTaylor
No console errors, it serves fine. The issue is for some reason is that the event binding and 2 way bindings dont function properly when I serve it from VScode where as when I do the same thing with the same code on stackblitz everything works. (there were never any console errors on VSCode nor Stackblitz)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257219/discussion-between-devan-and-brandon-taylor).